# INSERT INTO a MSSQL table through a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
users table
+----+----------+-------+-----+
| id | username | email | ... |
+----+----------+-------+-----+

APIkeys table
+----+--------+-----+---------+------+
| id | userId | key | expires | used |
+----+--------+-----+---------+------+
```

and a view:

```
ValidAPIkeys
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+
| users.username | APIkeys.key | apikeys.expires |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

The view displays only those values whose `used` is 0 and `expires` is more than now. This works great and even `UPDATE` works fine. What I need now is being able to insert values to (in the end) the `APIkeys` table **through** the view, something like `INSERT INTO [dbo].[ValidAPIkeys] (username, key) VALUES ('myUserName', 'someCryptographicNonsense')`. What I want this to do is to get the id of `myUserName` from `users` and then do a `INSERT INTO [dbo].[APIkeys] (userId, key) VALUES ('whateverHeGetsFromMaybeASelectStatement-id', 'someCryptographicNonsense')`.

I was wondering if this was at all possible. I remember doing something like this in Access but can't figure out how it worked. If this isn't possible I can always define a variable with the id and then use that. I just feel like a view like this would be a bit prettier.

Thank you for any feedback. If you feel so, just tell me I am a complete idiot for using MSSQL as a toaster for breakfast, I try to learn stuff my way :)

Comment: You can't insert into a view if the view contains more than 1 base table. How would it know where to put the information for each table?

Comment: Access is able to do that and it is handled by ADO engine. the story is different in SQL Server

Comment: @SeanLange that is partially what I am asking. If there is a way to specify it

Comment: If your view has more than one table then you need to add a trigger to the view so you can add logic to put the records in the correct place. BTW, get over any concept of inserting "in the end". You can't insert to a particular place. You can only use an `ORDER BY` in a `SELECT` to return it in the order that you want.

Comment: @FLICKER to is this a no-go? Should I try a different approach? What would you suggest as a clean solution that isn't too complicated to interact with from outside the SQL server (With C#, for example). What I am trying to avoid is too much SQL code in my C# program

Comment: @MichalKrejčí, i think you should use INSTEAD OF TRIGGER for your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two approaches to updating data in a view.  These are explained pretty clearly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql#updatable-views).

The first is to use an updatable view.  This is basically a view that has no aggregations and all the updates are on only a single table (there are other restrictions).  This may be sufficient for your purposes.

If the view is more complicated, you can use `INSTEAD OF` triggers on the view.  This this allows the trigger to modify the underlying tables, as necessary, based on the view definition.

Comment: I used the INSTEAD OF, which worked great. Thanks for the help.